# Rust lifetimes when closure created by struct method takes a mutable referece to that struct

Tags: rust, gpio, sysfs

I am new to rust, and especially to embedded rust. I have written something which maintains an 'alarm system', which can be in a variety of defined states. The Alarm struct, when transitioning to the `armed` state, sets up a GPIO pin interrupt with a closure that should be able to set the alarm's state to `Alarm` when triggered. The compiler complains that there is no guarantee that the closure will not outlive the struct. I understand the issue, but I am not clear on how to fix it.

```
use crate::pins::CustomPin;
use sysfs_gpio::Pin;
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum States {
    Disarmed,
    Armed,
    Alarm,
    Error,
}
pub struct Alarm {
    pub state: States,
    pub trigger_pin: Pin,
}
impl Alarm {
    pub fn arm(&mut self) -> () { // `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
        match self.trigger_pin.set_interrupt(Box::new(|| self.trigger())) { //...is captured and required to live as long as `'static` here
            Ok(_) => self.update(States::Armed),
            Err(_) => self.update(States::Error),
        };
    }
    pub fn disarm(&mut self) -> () {
        self.update(States::Disarmed);
    }
    pub fn trigger(&mut self) -> () {
        self.update(States::Alarm);
    }
    pub fn new(trigger_pin: u64) -> Alarm {
        let input = Pin::new(trigger_pin);
        Alarm {
            state: States::Disarmed,
            trigger_pin: input,
        }
    }
    fn update(&mut self, state: States) -> () {
        self.state = state;
    }
}
```

--

```
extern crate sysfs_gpio;
use sysfs_gpio::{Direction, Edge, Pin};
pub trait CustomPin {
    fn set_interrupt(&self, callback: Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>) -> sysfs_gpio::Result<()>;
}
impl CustomPin for Pin {
    fn set_interrupt(&self, callback: Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>) -> sysfs_gpio::Result<()> {
        self.with_exported(|| {
            self.set_direction(Direction::In)?;
            self.set_edge(Edge::FallingEdge)?;
            let mut poller = self.get_poller()?;
            loop {
                match poller.poll(1000)? {
                    Some(_) => callback(),
                    None => (),
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I understand the compiler message, but I don't know how to fix it. I considered a `RefCell`, but my understanding is that this would force the Alarm to live for as long as the closure, when in fact, the closure should not outlive the Alarm.

I suppose the point fundamentally is that I don't know how to drop that closure explicitly.

Comment: A side note: GPIO sysfs is deprecated and must not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `Box` assumes a `static` lifetime unless explicitly stated otherwise. Consequently, the lifetime problem in your example can be fixed by defining an explicit lifetime parameter to the trait like:

```
pub trait CustomPin {
    fn set_interrupt<'a>(&self, callback: Box<dyn FnMut() -> () + 'a>) -> sysfs_gpio::Result<()>;
}
```

Unfortunately, there are more fundamental ownership issues in your example that the borrow checker will reject. Your essential problem is that you're referencing `self` from every closure, especially even from functions requiring `&mut self`. This will always fail, you need an `Rc` or similar constructs to reference the same `Alarm` struct from multiple places following the "average C++ construct" you're probably migrating from.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm not actually migrating from anything, I'm a python dev, new to rust. So this is fundamentally the wrong approach?

Comment: Not wrong in general, it works fine for usual (garbage-collected or unsafe) environments. You simply have to think somewhat differently and be more prepared using proper ownership constructs to "convince the borrow checker".